# Transition Manager event complete

Tags: actionscript-3

I have the following code

```
      TransitionManager.start(babyPreloader,{type:Fade, direction:Transition.OUT,      duration:0.5, easing:Regular.easeOut});
      var tempPreloader:DisplayObject = babyPreloader as DisplayObject; 
      this.removeChild(tempPreloader);
```

But since this does not wait for the transition to complete. I cannot see the transition happening. Is there a way to have a even listener for transition complete?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use [TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/) for example:

```
TweenMax.to(babyPreloader, 0.5, {alpha:0, onComplete:done});

...

private function done():void
{
   removeChild(babyPreloader);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
var ts:TransitionManager = new TransitionManager(root_Mc);
fl_doTransition();
function fl_doTransition():void
{
    ts.addEventListener("allTransitionsInDone", done);  
    ts.startTransition({type:Blinds, direction:Transition.IN, duration:0.25});   

   //OR in case you are using Transition.OUT 
   //ts.addEventListener("allTransitionsOutDone", done);  
   //ts.startTransition({type:Blinds, direction:Transition.OUT, duration:0.25});

 }

    function done(e:Event):void 
    {
        trace( "yay!!");
    }
```

Comment: Voted up your answer. Remark: your duration value should rather be 2 or 3 to be more demonstrative.